# Mapping non-ascii, long column names in SQLAlchemy fails with NoSuchColumnError

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

Could it be that RowProxy objects' keys are truncated to some length?

I've a legacy MSSQL database that has some column names with accented letters.

I'm mapping it's columns to python properties with the following code:

```
@event.listens_for(Table, "column_reflect")
def column_reflect(inspector, table, column_info):
    if table.name == 'D_Allomanylista_Komplex_V':
        # set column.key = "attr_<lower_case_name>"
        columns_to_change = {
            'Allapot': 'allapot',
            'BIZTNEVE': 'biztosito_neve',
            u'Levelez\xe9siC\xedmUtca': 'LevelezesiCimUtca',
            u'Szerz\u0151d\xe9sSorsz\xe1m': 'SzerzodesSzam',
        }
        column_info['key'] = columns_to_change.get(column_info['name'], column_info['name'])

komplex_table = inspect_komplex_table()

class BiztositasokModel(Base):
    __table__ = komplex_table
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'primary_key': [
            komplex_table.c[u'KTVSZAM'],
            komplex_table.c[u'NyugtaSzam'],
            komplex_table.c[u'ajanlatszam'],
            komplex_table.c['SzerzodesSzam'],
            ],
        'include_properties': [
            'biztosito_neve',
            komplex_table.c['allapot'],
            komplex_table.c['LevelezesiCimUtca'],
            komplex_table.c['SzerzodesSzam'],
            'KTVSZAM', 'NyugtaSzam', 'ajanlatszam'],
    }
```

Unfortunately, this code gives an error when I try to query, stating that the `SzerzodesSzam` column does not exist.

```
/Users/viktornagy/.virtualenvs/dosszie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.pyc in _instance(row, result)
    361             identitykey = (
    362                 identity_class,
--> 363                 tuple([row[column] for column in pk_cols])
    364             )
    365

/Users/viktornagy/.virtualenvs/dosszie/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.pyc in _key_fallback(self, key, raiseerr)
    329                 raise exc.NoSuchColumnError(
    330                     "Could not locate column in row for column '%s'" %
--> 331                     expression._string_or_unprintable(key))
    332             else:
    333                 return None

NoSuchColumnError: "Could not locate column in row for column 'D_Allomanylista_Komplex_V.Szerz\\u0151d\\xe9sSorsz\\xe1m'"
```

I went into debugging mode to find out the root of the issue, and found that at line 363 above the column is `Column('Szerz\u0151d\xe9sSorsz\xe1m', INTEGER(), table=<D_Allomanylista_Komplex_V>, key='SzerzodesSzam', nullable=False)` while the corresponding `row.key()` is `u'D_Allomanylista_Komplex_V_Szerz\u0151d\xe9sSorsz'`. As if the key would be truncated (`u'Szerz\u0151d\xe9sSorsz'` once and `u'Szerz\u0151d\xe9sSorsz\xe1m'` at another point).

Querying `row[u'D_Allomanylista_Komplex_V_Szerz\u0151d\xe9sSorsz']` indeed works, and gives the expected result.

Is there a way to avoid this truncation?

Answer (score 0):

The above seems to be a limitation of the pyodbc driver. Switching to pymssql solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

works for me (even on OSX with freetds 0.86, typically this is where unicode DDL falls over badly):

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'D_Allomanylista_Komplex_V'

    bar = Column(u'Szerz\u0151d\xe9sSorsz\xe1m', INTEGER(), autoincrement=False, primary_key=True)

e = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@ms_2008", echo=True)

c = e.connect()
t = c.begin()

Base.metadata.create_all(c)

s = Session(c)
s.add(Foo(bar=5))
s.commit()

row = s.query(Foo).first()

assert row.bar == 5
```

output:

```
CREATE TABLE [D_Allomanylista_Komplex_V] (
    [SzerződésSorszám] INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY ([SzerződésSorszám])
)

2014-07-24 19:15:22,504 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2014-07-24 19:15:22,507 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO [D_Allomanylista_Komplex_V] ([SzerződésSorszám]) VALUES (?)
2014-07-24 19:15:22,507 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (5,)
2014-07-24 19:15:22,510 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT TOP 1 [D_Allomanylista_Komplex_V].[SzerződésSorszám] AS [D_Allomanylista_Komplex_V_SzerződésSorszám] 
FROM [D_Allomanylista_Komplex_V]
```

Comment: I think the main difference b/w your example and mine is that I'm creating the Table using inspection, while you build it declaratively. Thus I'm attaching a misteriously built Table to my declarative class. The error is not in connecting the Table and the declarative class, but between the Table and the real mssql columns.